# In ggplot how to make fill argument works in geom_dotplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
    olympics <-
readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-07-27/olympics.csv')    


olympics <- olympics %>% mutate(medal = as.factor(medal),
                               year =  as.factor(year))
judo <- olympics %>% filter(sport == 'Judo', team == 'Japan') %>% drop_na() %>%
                          select(name, sex, age, team, year,  medal) %>% arrange(year)
 
  ggplot(data = judo) +
    geom_dotplot(aes(x = year, group = year, fill = medal), binwidth = .25) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('#b08d57','#FFD700','#C0C0C0'))
```

My problems is that I am not able to fill the dots properly with the values of `scale_fill_manual()` function.

Comment: Its not working. If you look in the year 1964 it should give me 4 dots. When I remove the `group` argument the medals are not counted. It should have 4 gold medals and one silver medal

Comment: Use `geom_dotplot(aes(x = year, fill = medal), binwidth = .25, stackgroups = TRUE, binpositions = "all")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove the `group` aesthetic - it's overriding the separation (grouping) that naturally occurs when you group by the `fill` aesthetic.  The `group` aesthetic seems to take priority over the `fill` aesthetic, so your fill is never applied over top of the group.   Your data will already naturally be grouped by year since this is the `x` aesthetic.

Oh, and I changed the ordering of the factor `judo$medal` to match the typical "Bronze, Silver, Gold".  Consequently, your argument for `values` was changed to a named vector to ensure the proper mapping.

```
judo$medal <- factor(judo$medal, levels=c('Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold'))

ggplot(data = judo) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(x = year, fill = medal), binwidth = .25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('Bronze'='#b08d57','Gold'='#FFD700','Silver'= '#C0C0C0'))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing @chemdork123! Thanks!